# Run a batch file creating a task in Windows 7 task scheduler without UAC popup

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I need to run a batch file to create a task in Windows 7 Task Scheduler and I'm running into permission problems and UAC issues. And of course this same code worked flawlessly on Windows XP.

I've tried creating my command line one-liner to run with highest privileges and user the SYSTEM username but I still get an access denied error inside the command prompt. Now if I right click the script and click run CMD as administrator everything works the way its supposed to. However I'm making this for more than just myself. I can't have over 500 different users having to perform these right clicks since this process is meant to be somewhat automated.

So I'm guessing this script will never run if the logged in user trying to run it is anything less than an admin, correct? Is there any automated way to create a task to put in scheduler via command line without having popups? At this point I feel like this question has been asked thousands of times.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, it sounds like you're saying, *I have a batch file, and this batch file creates a scheduled task in windows*.  If i'm correct, then the batch file only needs to be executed once?  In any case, then it makes for the UAC to ask the user if it's ok to run an elevated command, otherwise people could do all sorts of nasty tasks.

Comment: (1) You don't need to be an admin to create scheduled tasks, provided you aren't asking for those tasks to be run with admin privilege themselves.  (2) If the task does need admin privilege then obviously you have to be an admin to create it, and yes you need to approve it via the UAC dialog - but that doesn't mean you have to right-click anything.  In this situation, by the way, if the "500 different users" aren't all admins, then you're doing it wrong; *someone* must have admin privilege on each of those computers, and you should be talking to the admins, not the end users.

Comment: In particular, if the 500+ machines are all in the same domain, the domain administrators should be able to run the script, with admin privilege, on all of the machines without the end-users being involved at all - though this may be more or less difficult depending on the nature of the enterprise, e.g., whether the machines are always turned on during the day, whether they are always turned off at the end of the day, whether they are using an IT management solution, and so on.